# Get Children Of JSONArray

Tags: java, json, thymeleaf

How can i get children of JSONArray? I'm trying to get Elasticsearch query JSON results to table with Thymeleaf (Spring Boot). Want to show results as table, couldn't do with DTO for results. Or an alternative method should i do with Javascript?

**Current Output:**
[image]

**Desired Output:**
i want to show id, fullname, lastname seperately. Firstly need to get child of `elements`, `_source`; then child of `_source`, every `fullname`, `lastname`, `id`
[image]

```
String json = searchService.searchFromQuery(query.trim().toLowerCase()).getElements(); 
JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(json);

                      
        model.addAttribute("query", jsonObj); //related with thymeleaf
```

**JSON:**

```
{"highlight":{"lastName":["<em>Asdfasd<\/em>"]},"_index":"user","_type":"_doc","_source":{"firstName":"Test","lastName":"Asdfasd","modificationDate":1595572482000,"_class":"com.example.springmysqlelastic.model.UserModel","id":1},"_id":"1","sort":[1],"_score":null}

{"highlight":{"lastName":["<em>sadasd<\/em>"]},"_index":"user","_type":"_doc","_source":{"firstName":"asfas","lastName":"sadasd","modificationDate":1595572482000,"_class":"com.example.springmysqlelastic.model.UserModel","id":2},"_id":"2","sort":[2],"_score":null}
```

**Thymeleaf HTML (just related part)**

```
<tr th:each="food : ${query}">
<td th:text="${food}">

<!--<td th:text="${food.id}"></td> Cant use like this because there is no DTO for search query (exists for "User")
<td th:text="${food.firstName}"></td>
<td th:text="${food.lastName}"></td>-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another implementation using library from json.org.

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class ProcessJson {
 public void test(String str) throws JSONException {
  JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);  //initial JSONObject (See explanation 
                                             //section below)
  JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("results");  //"results" JSONArray
  JSONObject item=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);//1st JSONObject inside "results" JSONArr 

  JSONArray jsonArrayTimes = item.getJSONArray("times");  //"times" JSONArray

  for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayTimes.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println(jsonArrayTimes.getInt(i));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["_source"] is not a JSONArray.] with root cause @Satish Hawalppagol

Comment: String json = searchService.searchFromQuery(query.trim().toLowerCase()).getElements(); 
json = json.substring(1, json.length() - 1);
JSONObject jsona = new JSONObject(json);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsona.getJSONArray("_source");

Comment: if i do JSONObject jsonas = jsona.getJSONObject("_source"); it shows this correctly BUT I NEED ALL CHILDREN, not 1. This shows only first.https://i.ibb.co/rb7Tc8c/image.png

Comment: I can shows the firstname String str = jsona.getJSONObject("_source").getString("firstName");

So how can i show all json array, not only first one.